# How to get more than 1000 entities from an azure table storage query?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, limit, azure-table-storage

I have read that azure table storage queries give maximum of 1000 entities and we have to make use of continuation tokens to fetch the next set of entities. I am just looking for an easy way to do that. All I want to do is fetch all the entities that the query should actually return and not just the 1000 entities. I have read @smarx post [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-tables-expect-continuation-tokens-seriously)
 and he mentions about `ExecuteAll` method in `TableStorageDataServiceQuery` but this seems to have deprecated as I cant find `TableStorageDataServiceQuery` in the storage client library.

I also found this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135718.aspx) documentation on how to handle the continuation tokens to fetch all the entities. I just want to know if this is the best way to get all the entities, I dont need any pagination. Or is there any ExecuteAll esque method that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the AsTableServiceQuery like so:

```
var data = context.CreateQuery<SomeEntity>("table").AsTableServiceQuery<SomeEntity>().Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit grotesque - and not a great long term solution - but I forked the Azure Storage Driver for Linqpad specifically to get all records from table storage.

https://github.com/ryan1234/AzureStorageDriver

Get it, build it and install it with Linqpad. An example query that goes against it in Linqpad:

```
var logs = (from log in SBEmailWorkerRole.ToList()
            select new {
                LogEntry = log.LogEntry,
                CreateDate = log.Timestamp.ToLocalTime()
            }).ToList();

logs.OrderByDescending(l => l.CreateDate).Dump("Logs");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to query table storage, but the easiest way is to create a CloudTable object, create a TableQuery object, then call ExecuteQuery on the CloudTable object passing in the TableQuery object.

The first result from http://www.bing.com/search?q=azure+table+storage+query&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=azure+table+storage+query&sc=8-25&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=eb5a88d975df445ab665fbf5082fa7c8 will take you to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/ which shows examples of how to do this.

Answer (score -3):

If my understanding of documents is correct, there is no way to do that.

Please be aware that continuation tokens can be returned even when number of records < 1000. It is a good idea to always check for continuation tokens when executing queires.

Also, why do you want to return more than 1000 records? what is the use case?