# PHP Azure Table Storage + Time out

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using PHP to retrieve all rows from partition(s). I am using the below method to get all rows

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/table-service/#RetEntitiesInPartition

Facing a unique issue:  If i am using one partition result is returned, using more than one partition with OR Clause returns no results.

Seems like to me two issues:

1. Partition with OR Condition and Filter on other column causing something turn mental.
2. There is issue with the PHP SDK ( Version 2.0 )

Any help will be highly appreciated,

1. Queries have a `Partition` column properly used. e,g if I am running this query ( 10 rows against two partitions)

   ```
   ( cid eq '18831') and ( (PartitionKey eq '2013100606') or (PartitionKey eq '2013100607') )
   ```

   There is no response when partitionkey have more than one values with OR Clause using PHP script. Using storage explorer application Seems like it take more than 5 seconds for 10 rows to pull from two partitions. ( All i have is 10 rows no other data in both partitions)

If I access only one Partition it returns the rows.

```
( cid eq '18831') and ( (PartitionKey eq '2013100607') )  // Works fine
```

There are 10 rows in each partition, if i access single partition value it works fine.

Also please note I am using expect100Continue and Nagle turned off.

```
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" useNagleAlgorithm="false"/> 
    </settings> 
<connectionManagement> 
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "48" /> 
    </connectionManagement>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get more than 1000 entities from an azure table storage query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615673/how-to-get-more-than-1000-entities-from-an-azure-table-storage-query)

Comment: i found this is issue with partition value, if query having more than 1 partition value with OR clause, the scripts take very long to execute more than 5 seconds even for 10 rows.   REST API returns no records for execution time more than 5 seconds.

Comment: I updated the Question as well.

Comment: Try reversing the query and see if that makes any difference -  `( (PartitionKey eq '2013100606') or (PartitionKey eq '2013100607') ) and ( cid eq '18831')`.

Comment: Did that but same No result returned by PHP Script.  Even i run using Storage explorer software, query takes 10+ seconds to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the blog post by Windows Azure Storage team - [`How to get most out of Windows Azure Tables`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx) (scroll down to `Queries` section in the post, point #4), queries involving **`OR`** are not optimized and would result in full table scan. You may be running into issues because of that.

You may want to change your query to avoid this situation. A few things you could try are:

```
((PartitionKey ge '2013100606') and (PartitionKey le '2013100607')) and (cid eq '18831')

(PartitionKey eq '2013100606' and cid eq '18831') or (PartitionKey eq '2013100607' and cid eq '18831')
```

See if doing any of these help. Instead of 2nd query, you could fire two separate queries in parallel.